# Try to run the the weave-network-plugin in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, weave

first of all I would like to say that I am a beginner in the kubernetes-topic and I have the problem that I couldn't reach a pod (via a service) when I give the service a fixed IP so I would like to summary the things I think I had understand and maybe someone here can correct me or aknowledge my way to resolve my problem.

I deploy my cluster with the ansible-script kubespray on baremetal (2 Nodes with CentOS 7) and I configure the script and resulting cluster as follow:

- proxy-Mode: ipvs
- service-network: 10.0.0.0/24
- pod-network: 10.0.1.0/24
- network-plugin: weave-net
- dns_mode: dnsmasq_kubedns

and after the deployment was successfully I can deploy pods, services, secrets etc. to the cluster so it seems for me it works fine, but when I now to define an external IP i.e. like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    name: nginx
  externalIPs:
  - "192.168.1.42"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: gluster-pod1
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-slim:0.8
    ports:
    - name: web
      containerPort: 80
```

I can reach the pod by his internal IP, by the IP of the endpoint and by the IP of the master but not by the IP I define for this service, when I try this I get by curl the error: "no route to host" the strange this for me is when I set the IP for the service as the same IP as the kubernetes master i.e.

```
...
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    name: nginx
  externalIPs:
  - "192.168.1.1"
```

I can reach the pod.

Now after I read a lot of documentation and howto's the problem is resolveable when I configure my own load balancer for the management of external IPs because if I didn't define an fixed IP the service waiting with the status "pending" for an external IP.

But unfortunately after all the reading of the documentation I am not sure if the architecture really works this way I mean
pod <-> service <-> load-balancer (<-> DHCP)

so I can reach the pod via the service.

As I started I would like to close this post I am not sure this is the right direction to resolve my problem. That's why I would very grateful if someone can confirm me or correct me :-)
best regards
Dan

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337551/ipvsadm-not-showing-any-entry-in-kubeadm-cluster)

Comment: Did you follow some manual, if yes could you link it so I can try to reproduce the issue. Also the subnet of the pod network seems to be too narrow, try to use /16.